# Change language in Bot Framework Composer

Tags: bot-framework-composer

I'm using v1.0.1 and when I create a new bot, the bot is set to *en-us* automatically. This also affects LUIS apps created by bot framework composer which are set to *en-us* too. I want to create a bot for german language using german LUIS app.

Is there any way to change the language of the bot in Microsoft Bot Framework Composer?

**Edit**

According to [this](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/1736#issuecomment-602120874) multi language recognizers will be available in august 2020 at the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to work with translation middleware for the time being though? It would still have you to set up the LUIS app in English, but translate the user/bot messages via the middleware. Maybe not ideal, but if it can be a help for now.

There is an ongoing question for how to use translation middleware in Bot Framework Composer here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues/3514.

An example of translation middleware is available here: https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/17.multilingual-bot

Comment: Thanks but translating each message to or from bot is far from ideal for our application because we use very specific vocabularies. We really need to create a bot in german using a german luis model.

Comment: Hehe, I understand that it is definitely not ideal. I was just offering it was a temporary workaround, given that it could be until August until a more definitive solution will be available in Bot Framework Composer.

Comment: @ooorndtski Actually, it looks like there is a way to define the LUIS language in Bot Framework Composer. Go to Settings > Bot Settings > Find Luis node > "defaultLanguage": "en-us". You can change the language here based on this list: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-language-support. I haven't been able to test yet myself, but it looks like it should do exactly what you are looking for?

Comment: I've tested it but it did not work. I've set the defaultLanguage to "de-DE" but nevertheless the luis app is created using "en-US" culture.

Comment: Hey everyone, has anything happened over time in regard to this topic? Is there meanwhile a better method than the use of a translation middleware?